# Did we briefly get closed?

Tags: discussion

For a moment it looked like the private beta had been shut down. Resurrection seems a bit ominous. Lets try harder shall we? Invite friends.

Maybe next time we need a booth at SIGGRAPH? If this resurrection doesn't work better for us.

Comment: Yes new people would make a big difference since the majority of our current community seem to be inactive. We need enough questions over the next few days to prove we're ready for a public beta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes we did get briefly (accidentally) closed, as you can see from the **[chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23587595#23587595)**. As this was fixed within a couple of hours it is hoped that most people will have been unaffected. I did suggest emailing the committers in case anyone had seen the site closed down and therefore had no reason to come back and find out that it was only temporary.

No emails have been sent yet as it may not be necessary. There's the **[possibility of sending a group email on Monday](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23588637#23588637)** if it seems like we have lost members.

If you find that you are still redirected to Area 51, and unable to access the front page of our site, you may need to clear your browser's cache (that's what worked for me yesterday).

If you happen to know of any users who were under the impression that we had closed permanently (as I was yesterday), and who didn't find out for themselves that we're back up, please mention it here in case it makes the difference in the decision on whether to send out an email.

Comment: I was a bit perplexed about this. Then i shook my shoulders and said to myself. Guess it was a quck week :) Ive never been good with tracking of time.