# Do we need a scope change to expand?

Tags: discussion

We've been [given an extra week](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/114/231) to prove we are ready for public beta. We've had that week, and more. We still haven't progressed to public beta. However, we still haven't been shut down either, apart from [temporarily accidentally](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120/did-we-briefly-get-closed).

We certainly haven't been forgotten. I noticed recently that Robert Cartaino closed a clearly off topic question within minutes of posting, so Stack Exchange staff are obviously watching our site closely and trying to guide it in the right direction.

This suggests to me that we are doing *only just* well enough to survive a few more days, but not well enough to justify a public beta yet. We had a big jump up in question rate, but it's dropped again.

If you browse through our [new users](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=NewUsers&sort=creationdate) you will see that despite being a "private" beta, every day we have a few new users sign up and have a look around the site. However, most of them don't post any questions or answers. Is this because they are all just browsing? Or might some of them ask a question if we had a slightly broader range of topics?

Is there any topic that we haven't seen/welcomed yet, that could make sense as part of our scope and make people more likely to stay and ask questions? Is it a good idea to do so? Is there any other way to both increase our number of questions, and increase our range of topics covered *within our current scope?*

---

**Please share your opinions here, whether you are one of our regular question and answer posters, or one of the many silent visitors we have every day - it's you this question is about...**

Answer (score 8):

You're reading too much into it. This site has been slated for public launch, but we typically don't throw that switch until Monday or Tuesday. Barring any technical difficulties, this site will be going public early this coming week.

Comment: Wooo... and here i was allready thinking we were too small.

Comment: I'm so happy to be wrong :)

Comment: Yeeee, great news!