# Who should our moderators be?

Tags: discussion, moderation

[We'll be making it to public beta](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/124/16) (yay!). So I think it's time for the next big [essential beta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223675/201409):

> If your meta site does not have a post to nominate Moderators, start one now! Pro Tem appointments will begin about two weeks after the site is created. The more guidance we receive, the more informed our choice. [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)

- **Each nomination should be a separate answer**. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by leaving a comment or editing the answer. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
- Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

We're looking for members of this site who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

It's also good if the moderators:

- Are members with participation in both the meta and main site.
- Participated in Area 51, generate social network referrals, or blog about the site.
- Are members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

---

<sub>Shamelessly copied from [meta.puzzling](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/171/2450).</sub>

Comment: How many pro term mods do we get 1 or 2

Comment: @joojaa Normally 3.

Comment: Then maybe more than 3 candidates would put democracy forward better. No?

Comment: @joojaa You're free to nominate as many candidates as you like.

Comment: @joojaa What democracy? The community team selects the pro tem moderators unilaterally, based on a multitude of factors; it's not like the nominee with the most upvotes has an automatic right to be a moderator.

Comment: Yes but candidates can self organize talk amongst themselves. Then withdraw. If we have 3 good ones in the pool then presumaby you would ask for those. If on the otherhand we dont do this your more likely to use a wild card... @Chris

Comment: @joojaa Only to a point. For example, on PPCG, here's the [moderator nomination](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57/3) thread and here's the [pro tem announcement](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/220/3) thread. You'll notice that most of the appointed pro tems did not even appear in the nomination thread. ;-) Anyway, this thread is still good for people to indicate interest in moderation, but, it's definitely not a democracy and I just wanted to clear up any potential misunderstandings about that.

Comment: yes but thats why its important to to talk it out. Because then you are more likely to believe in the candidates. If this is the level of activity you would be better of pulling from a hat. @Chris

Comment: @joojaa Agree that people should discuss their interest in moderation, and users should feel free to demonstrate support for candidates they like, just with the understanding that it's not binding in any way.

Comment: Looks like we have four worthy candidates. What happens next?

Comment: @Pseudonym 3 candidates. Nathan declined his nomination. I guess we'll just wait for community team to make a decision.

Answer (score 22):

I would also like to nominate [trichoplax](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/users/231/trichoplax).

[image: profile for trichoplax at Computer Graphics Stack Exchange, Q&A for computer graphics researchers and programmers]


[image: profile for trichoplax at Computer Graphics Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for computer graphics researchers and programmers]


[profile for trichoplax on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/4066709.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/4066709)

- trichoplax has been helping to build this community since the last private beta a year ago. He is clearly very interested in the success of this community.
- trichoplax has probably been *the* most active user during the private beta. He contributed a whopping 40 posts on main (the second most seems to be 25) and is among the top 3 users by reputation.
- He also has the highest [participation on meta](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/users) with similar stats as on main. His posts clearly show that he cares about the quality of our content and that he knows what's important when building a new community.
- I've known trichoplax for a while from [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/): he is a very active chat user and he is, without exaggeration, one of the most polite and patient people I've "met" on Stack Exchange, even when he's interacting with... difficult... users. This is probably the single most important quality for a good moderator.

---

I'm trichoplax, and I'd like to accept this nomination. Martin was kind enough to answer my questions on what it's like being a mod, and I can confirm that I will have plenty of time for helping to support the community while it grows.

I'm delighted that we've managed to make it through private beta this time around - huge thanks to everyone who contributed. I'm keen to keep up the momentum we've built and get this site more established.

I have a strong interest in computer graphics but no technical experience - I haven't worked in the field and have no qualifications related to it. I'm looking forward to this community helping me learn more. The main thing I can offer is being patient and impartial. Until I catch up I'll defer to others for decisions that require graphics expertise.

Answer (score 11):

I'd like to nominate [Nathan Reed](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/users/48/nathan-reed).

[image: profile for Nathan Reed at Computer Graphics Stack Exchange, Q&A for computer graphics researchers and programmers]


[image: profile for Nathan Reed at Computer Graphics Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for computer graphics researchers and programmers]


[profile for Nathan Reed on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/903422.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/903422)

Nathan has [high activity](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74985?phase=beta&users=mostactive#tab-top), [highest rep](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74985?phase=beta&users=reputation#tab-top), and posts [many very high quality answers](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/users/48/nathan-reed?tab=answers) based on expert knowledge. Also relevant to suitability as a mod is the high activity in the [review queues](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/review), already helping to keep the site running smoothly. All these things were the case in last year's private beta and have been consistently the case again this year.

I was particularly impressed with a question for which Nathan performed testing of two different approaches in order to give an evidence based answer, rather than just answering based on intuition. [This answer](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/65/what-is-the-optimal-radius-of-gaussian-distribution-for-determining-pixel-colour/75#75) links to the blog post that developed from that original answer last time around. Not only is this an excellent way to approach answering, but it also suggests someone who will also treat any disputes between community members in a similar objective manner. Because of this, Nathan is someone I would be happy to accept a decision from, even if not in my favour.

On top of this Nathan referred a large number of new members during commitment phase, making a big difference in helping us reach private beta. Nathan will clearly be of great value to this community whether a mod or not, and I'm hoping we will also benefit from having such a dedicated, objective member as a moderator.

Comment: I'm flattered, but I have to decline this nomination. Being a moderator is a significant responsibility and time commitment, and unfortunately not something I can take on right now.

Comment: @NathanReed as I said, it's great to have you here mod or not.

Answer (score 9):

I would like to nominate myself.

Some relevant user flairs on this and other sites:

[image: profile for Martin Büttner at Computer Graphics Stack Exchange, Q&A for computer graphics researchers and programmers]


[image: profile for Martin Büttner at Computer Graphics Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for computer graphics researchers and programmers]


[image: profile for Martin Büttner at Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange, Q&A for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers]


[profile for Martin Büttner on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1793115.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/1793115)

Why Computer Graphics SE?

- I've been very excited about this SE and have eagerly awaited the beta phase over the past year. I've been following the proposal from very early on and provided several well-received example questions which have been made into well-received real questions by now.
- I've been a computer graphics enthusiast for several years and will be starting PhD studies in the field this October. I really want to see this site succeed, because I think that an information resource with SE's high quality is still missing on the internet.

Why me?

- I have been a moderator (pro tempore) on [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) for the past 5 months, so I do already have moderation experience on a beta site. Judging by the moderate workload on PPCG and my high activity, I don't think moderating two sites will be detrimental to my contributions to either site.
- My [meta participation](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/users) on this site is very high, and I've been trying to work through the review queues as actively as I could. My questions and answers on meta hopefully show that I'm very interested in building this community while ensuring that our content is of high quality.
- I'm active [in our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26589/the-cornell-box) and I wish more of the other users were as well. ;)
- I don't like to praise to myself, so for some words about my person, I refer you to [my nomination on PPCG](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4929/8478).

Finally, let me pre-emptively address the stains on my record:

- My activity during this private beta has dropped off after the first two weeks. This was mostly because I was travelling, and I fully intend to pick up my previous activity levels (and have already begun to do so).
- I haven't written a single answer on main yet. While I have tried to contribute to the community with a number of questions which I hope will be of use to future visitors, I haven't done much graphics-related work recently. Therefore, I felt a bit out of the loop to provide sufficiently authoritative answers compared to our more expert users. With the PhD I'll be starting, I hope that this will change very soon and that I'll build the confidence to contribute to this community with answers as well.

Comment: I'll refrain from voting since I'm brand new to this community, but I just want to say that as an active user on PPCG I've seen firsthand what it's like to have Martin as a mod. His contributions to the community have been vast. I think he would do a fantastic job moderating on this site.

Comment: While your activity as a moderator on another site is quite relevant, I'm not sure the actual PPCG flair is.

Comment: @ChristianRau I figured if anyone wanted to check out my activity on a site where I'm a moderator, linking to it would be the most convenient way for them to get there.

Comment: In addition to having already demonstrated the ability to be a fair and much loved moderator on [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), before this Martin was also highly encouraging and inclusive of contributors at all levels in the PPCG Fortnightly challenges, which were an experiment in collaboration, and is exactly what we need for growing and uniting our community.

Answer (score 5):

I'll step up. I only stumbled upon the site just at the turn of public beta, but I've been an enthusiast ever since playing *Chuck Yaeger's Air Combat* on my 286 at age 12. And I hope to contribute (and learn) a great deal here.

I'm active on several sites and have been a (l)user of SO for over 4 years. ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/733077/luser-droog) ([C](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:733077+[c]) and [Postscript](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:733077+[postscript]) tags), [Music](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/1344/) ([guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:1344+[guitar]) and [theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:1344+[theory]) tags), [PPCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2381/luser-droog) ([code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:2381+[code-golf]) and [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:2381+[code-challenge]) tags). [Graphics on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:733077+[graphics]). [Graphical-output on PPCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:2381+[graphical-output]). And a few metas: [music](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1344/luser-droog), [PPCG](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2381/luser-droog).

I'm the primary author of an [open-source PostScript interpreter](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/xpost) (and [related](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/debug.ps) [tools](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/ibis.ps)) and thus am very interested in the algorithms and implementations of both vector-graphics and raster-graphics systems, and using these.

I'm also a participant on [usenet](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!profile/comp.lang.c/APn2wQdEi5QhcIEsQrxdk6niB-YTnHceZ8BNwOwDaO1mP9ZUb0vnXhb5R0jLrzuhhxfJbB0dlzQl) ([highlights](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/xpost-discuss/EwUA6NmwxQQ/discussion)), particularly [comp.lang.postscript](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!profile/comp.lang.postscript/APn2wQfG1ZzXc7Ni-ghXKm3ZuK5wGvApQfCNe9bOpNameh20m-E6tuTCc-_vDKvaSGDIqBw9XRLA) ([highlights](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/xpost-discuss/KJCesIt-AGw/discussion)). One very interesting saga began with ["Ping! luser droog..."](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.postscript/DXfU2xrRCxY/discussion)

I am sometimes impatient(*), but always (try to be) fair. If this means challenging the status quo for a good cause, so be it. If it means gentle handling of a new user who doesn't know the ropes, I'm there.

*I can often transform this into perseverance.

I would tend to refrain from voting to close if a question can be saved by editing. This might distinguish me somewhat from Martin, who must maintain a more severe policy over on code-golf (necessary there to prevent "dangling answers" which are only valid for a particular (early) revision of a question (challenge)). I feel we can be a little more lenient (and less discouraging) here to new users.

[image: profile for luser droog at Computer Graphics Stack Exchange, Q&A for computer graphics researchers and programmers]
 
[image: profile for luser droog at Computer Graphics Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for computer graphics researchers and programmers]

[image: profile for luser droog at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]
 [profile for luser droog on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/379598.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/379598/luser-droog)

Comment: Dont underestimate this score, stack overflow is not really super effective in giving score to people with very niche interests. You will get my vote.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but in case there is any need in the future, I will be dropping myself as a backup in here.

I'm currently writing my master's thesis at the chair of [Computer Graphic Systems](http://hpi.de/en/doellner/index.html) at the Hasso Plattner Institute, also being research scholar and student assistant.

[image: computer graphics stack exchange] [image: computer graphics meta]

In addition, I'm pro-tem moderatorator at the recently launched [Ethereum Stack Exchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/).

[image: ethereum stack exchange] [network profile http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1313419.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/1313419/5chdn)

Whenever you need a hand, ping me. :-)

Comment: Thanks for volunteering! I expect that if there is ever a need for a new mod in future, there will be a new meta post too. We would also make it featured so you don't miss it.